# Feed select option value with textbox/hidden input?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp-classic

I am currently looking to have the value of the following (id="categoryid")...

```
 <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="MM_setTextOfTextfield('categoryid','','1')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNotesModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Notes
  </button>

 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryid">
```

to feed into the option value below....

```
<select name="Category" required class="form-control">
           <option value="">Select...</option>
           <option value="______"><%=(rsNtsC.Fields.Item("NotesCategory").Value)%></option>
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm open to jQuery, AJAX and javascript solutions if necessary.

Many thanks

EDIT:
In my current set up the  uses a value in a SQL database as an ID number, like so. I'm mostly looking to replace getting the value from the database with whatever the textbox has:

```
<select name="Category" required class="form-control">
               <option value="">Select...</option>
               <%
While (NOT rsNtsC.EOF)
%>
               <option value="<%=(rsNtsC.Fields.Item("NotesCategoryID").Value)%>"><%=(rsNtsC.Fields.Item("NotesCategory").Value)%></option>
               <%
  rsNtsC.MoveNext()
Wend
If (rsNtsC.CursorType > 0) Then
  rsNtsC.MoveFirst
Else
  rsNtsC.Requery
End If
%>
             </select>
```

Comment: you mean to say that on button click you need to add `<option>` dynamically with the text coming from `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryid">`?

Comment: At the moment the value is stored in a SQL database (please see my edit). I basically have 3 buttons that will tie to 3 different CategoryIDs when they open a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a looking for a way to include the value of the `input` into the `select` use the code below.

But remember that as soon as the page gets reloaded the values of the `select` will be gone.

```js
function MM_setTextOfTextfield(input) {
  var count = $("select[name='Category'] option").length;
  $("select[name='Category']").append("<option val=\"" + count + "\">" + $("#" + input).val() + "</option>")
  $("#" + input).val("")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="MM_setTextOfTextfield('categoryid')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddNotesModal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Notes
  </button>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoryid">

<select name="Category" required class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sadly this isn't what I'm looking for it to do.
At the moment the value is stored in a SQL database (please see my edit). I basically have 3 buttons that will tie to 3 different CategoryIDs when they open a modal.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just attach a 'change' listener on the input field, detect when the value changed and append an option with the value and text to your select, something like this (not tested but it should work, I am in a hurry wight now ;-)):

```
$('#categoryid').on('change', function(){
var value = $(this).val();
$('select').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

Or if you want to attach the option on a button click, you just change the listener accordingly like so:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
var value = $('#categoryid').val();
$('select').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

But beware: when you have a form tag around those elements, you need to call e.preventDefault(); with e as an argument to function() if you do not want your browser to reload every time...